# How do I create a copy activity for a file whose name keeps changing?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have to copy a file from an HTTP source to Azure Blob Storage (ABS) using a copy activity in Azure Data Factory (ADF).

The fully-qualified path to the file has a date-stamp in it, so it keeps changing (e.g., `http://www.example.com/files/2022-12-13.zip`). Further I want to expand it into a directory in ABS that is also named based on the date (e.g., `<blob>/2022-12-13/`).

Is there a way to do this in ADF (preferably one that doesn't involve writing code)?

Comment: So, the source link for tomorrow's date would be `http://www.example.com/files/2022-12-14.zip`. If not, how are you getting the source http link?

Comment: I have solved a similar issue with writing code to check the "latest" file in my data lake directory, and then pick that one up. I could share the code here if you want, but since you're preferring a no-code solution I thought I'd check with you first.

Comment: @SaideepArikontham Yes, the name of the file changes as you have suggested.

Comment: @Psychotechnopath please go ahead & share the code (or at least the idea of how to do it). Even if I don't choose that solution, it might be helpful to others. Your solution uses the Data Movement Library?

Comment: I've added my solution below. I needed to select the most recent file from a folder under a blob container in ADLS2. I just used the Azure Data Lake Storage client library to interact with files in the data lake (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python), and then simply used string parsing to sort by date & extract most recent file from files. Hope it helps. Please let me know if additional clarification is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Since, your source is HTTP, you can build the URL dynamically like `http://www.example.com/files/yyyy-MM-dd.zip` where `yyyy-MM-dd` is today's date.

- Using `copy data` activity, create a source dataset for `HTTP` source with configurations set as below. Give the base URL as `http://www.example.com/files/` and relative URL as shown below:

```
@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-dd')}.zip
```

[image]

- Don't select `Preserve zip file name as folder` option.
- Now for sink, you can create your dataset for blob storage. Since you want to store it in a folder with `yyyy-MM-dd`, configure your blob storage sink dataset as shown below:

```
#folder structure here would be "op/yyyy-MM-dd/" 
#remove or add before the dynamic content to define your folder structure.
op/@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-dd')}
```

[image]

- Also change the file extension as required in sink settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement lately, and ended up solving this with code. You can either use an azure function to get the list of files from your data lake folder, or use a Synapse Notebook. Based on your requirements, you can select the latest/earliest/some other criterion in that specific blob --> folder. Here's how I did it:

```
# Use DataLakeServiceClient class from ADLS2 data lake API. 
# Can probably use similar API for blob storage. 
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient


# Function that initializes a connection to the data lake
def initialize_storage_account_connection(storage_account_name, storage_account_key):
    service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net",
                                           credential=storage_account_key)
    return service_client


# Function that returns the file paths of files in a certain folder
def list_directory_contents():
    # Initialize a file system client for blob container "raw"
    file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="raw")
    # Get the path objects of respective parquet files in specific table folders under the "raw" blob container
    paths = file_system_client.get_paths(path=path_to_folder)
    # Parse paths into a proper list
    path_list = [path.name for path in paths]
    return path_list


# Function that determines the most recent change file (I Needed most recent file but perhaps adapt according to needs)
def get_most_recent_timestamp():
    # Example of a path: 'change_data/test_table/changes_test_table2022-10-13T17:57:30.parquet'
    # Determine prefix length of path that has to be stripped away (for example: "change_data/test_table/changes_test_table" has a length of 41)
    prefix_length = len(path_to_change_table) + len('changes_') + len(table_name) + 1
    # Determine suffix length of path that has to be stripped away
    suffix_length = len('.parquet')
    # Strip away prefix and suffix for each path so only the timestamp remains. In example, only 2022-10-13T17:57:30 would remain.
    # Do this for all paths in directory_path_list
    time_stamp_list = [i[prefix_length:-suffix_length] for i in directory_path_list]
    # Sort the time stamps
    sorted_time_stamp_list = sorted(time_stamp_list, reverse=True)
    # Get and return most recent timestamp
    most_recent_timestamp = sorted_time_stamp_list[0]
    return most_recent_timestamp
```

And then just call the function:

```
path_to_change_table = f'change_data/{table_name}'
#TODO: get key from key-vault or use a managed identity
service_client = initialize_storage_account_connection('your_sa', 'your_sa_key')
directory_path_list = list_directory_contents()
most_recent_timestamp = get_most_recent_timestamp()
print(most_recent_timestamp)
```